# Matlab: using webwrite to send image through a simple REST API

Tags: matlab, rest

I was trying to do image classification through a web at service at  and
I had no problem to use curl to retrieve token:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Authorization:MY Key" -F "image_request[image]=@/path/to/myimage" -F "image_request[locale]=en-US" https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests
```

However, it is not successful when I tried webwrite, it returned "HTTP 400" error.

```
option=weboptions('KeyName','Authorization','KeyValue','mykey')
fid = fopen('/path/to/myimage');
img = fread(fid,Inf,'*uint8');
fclose(fid);
response=webwrite('https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests',...
  'image_request[image]',img,...
  'image_request[locale]','en-US',option);
```

I guess it because the function webwrite in this format doesn't support "multipart/form-data" and I need change the media type. Then I tried to send data as an JSON object

```
option=weboptions('KeyName','Authorization','KeyValue','mykey','MediaType','application/json')
data=struct('image_request[image]',im,'image_request[locale]','en-US');
response=webwrite('https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests',data,option)
```

But the field name in Matlab struct does not allow "[". 
Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the service you are using? Sorry, it's a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: the API doc of the service I am using is [link]https://cloudsight.readme.io/v1.0/docs. Basically i send an image and service returns a classification of the image: tell me if the images contains a dog, cat, car, etc.